# Is there a difference between 辞典 and 辞書 ？

Tags: meaning, words

Is there a difference between 辞典 and 辞書? I know that both terms refer to a dictionary. I am thinking that a 辞典 has pictures and possibly more volumes (encyclopedia) and a 辞書 does not.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12974/the-difference-between-%e8%be%9e%e6%9b%b8-and-%e5%ad%97%e5%bc%95/12976#12976

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **辞典**（じてん）: dictionary
- **辞書**（じしょ）: dictionary
- **事典**（じてん）: encyclopedia (with pictures and long descriptions)

Note that 辞典 and 事典 are different words with the same reading. 辞典 and 辞書 are basically synonyms, but 辞典 tends to be used as part of a compound or a dictionary name, whereas 辞書 is more widely used as a common noun for a dictionary.

Related:

- [The difference between 辞書 and 字引](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12974/5010)
- [What is the difference between jibiki and jisho?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41122/5010)

Comment: 事典 was also listed as an encyclopedia on jisho.org I did some more research!